# Error while opening DBeaver for Mac: You can’t open the application “DBeaver” because it is not supported on this type of Mac

Tags: database, macos, dbeaver

I have two accounts on my mac and Dbeaver only works on one account at the same time. In the another account, i get the following message "You can’t open the application “DBeaver” because it is not supported on this type of Mac."

Answer (score 3):

[this](https://www.mac-forums.com/threads/cannot-start-dbeaver-killed-9-from-cli.369812/post-1901145) has worked for me.

Uninstalling the broken instance, and re-installing it with `brew` has worked for me for some reason. It also restored my old connections.

`brew reinstall --cask dbeaver-community`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a Mac user myself however I'm aware that running something like SQL LocalDB/Express on Windows concurrently between two accounts isn't possible either.I believe it has something to do with the pre-existing instance you've launched on the other account. I'm going to assume it works swell on one account at a time?

Comment: Exactly, i have to reinstall the application everytime.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences-->Security & Privacy-->General, set 'Allow Apps etc' to 'Anywhere'

This helps me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Apple icon at top left corner:
2. Then click on System Settings:

[image]

3. A new menu will open just like below. Under the `Security` section, a new option will appear which will say "Allow DBeaver to Open Anyway". Select the `Open Anyway` option and your DBeaver will start running.

[image]